# Entity Framework Add-Migration fails with "Could not find assembly"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Using Package Manage Console in Visual Studio, when I run "Add-Migration MyMigrationName" on Company.Project1 (.NET Core 1.1) I get an error

```
Could not find assembly 'C:\path\to\my\solution\Company.Project2\.\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Company.Project1.dll'.
```

Answer (score 7):

The project you are running migrations on must be the startup project.